# Tow to add a new worksheet to Excel with interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I can create an Excel properly with 2 worksheets, and I can write a DataTable's data to *Sheet 1* and I want to write the same data to *Sheet 2* but *Sheet 2* seems blank. Why *"Sheet 2"* is blank?

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
if (xlApp == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    return;
}
xlApp.Visible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

{
    if (ws == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = ws2.get_Range("C1", "C7");

    for (int i = 0; i < main_dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ws.Cells[1, i + 1] = main_dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        aRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, i + 1];
        aRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15;
        aRange.Font.Bold = true;
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < main_dt.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < main_dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[r + 2, i + 1] = main_dt.Rows[r][i].ToString();
        }    
    }
}   

// WORKSHEET 2 ******************
wb.Sheets.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[2];

{
    if (ws2 == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = ws2.get_Range("C1", "C7");

    for (int i = 0; i < main_dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ws2.Cells[1, i + 1] = main_dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        aRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws2.Cells[1, i + 1];
        aRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15;
        aRange.Font.Bold = true;    
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < main_dt.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < main_dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ws2.Cells[r + 2, i + 1] = main_dt.Rows[r][i].ToString();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your Excel setup but by default an Excel workbook is created with 3 sheets. There is no need to add another sheet. `Worksheet ws2 = ws.Sheets[2] as Worksheet;` should be enough to get reference to Sheet2. Your code should be written in Sheet1 and Sheet2 from what I see...Also above `if (ws == null)` there is an extra `{` opening bracket - is that intentional? Also, the first `aRange` shouldn't it be `ws.get_Range` instead of `ws2` ?

Comment: by default in Excel versions < 2013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
wb.Sheets.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws2 = 
                      (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[2];
```

try:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws2 = 
                       (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.Add();
```

Comment: But by default there are 3 sheets in a new workbook. Why would you add another one when you can reference the already existing sheet with `wb.Sheets[2];`?

Comment: @mehow Excel 2013 has 1 sheet by default

Comment: @BenAaronson good point but I am sorry I may have missed out on something here but where exactly was Excel 2013 mentioned? Also even if it was 2013 those 2 lines are nearly the same.... i dont think this solves the problem though

Comment: @mehow Well you said "by default there are 3 sheets in a new workbook", but that's not true for all Excel versions

Comment: @mehow: to be sure that variable ws2 holds the newly created Sheet. When you add a new sheet, you are never sure that this one is Worksheet[2]. It could also be [3] or [4] or ... ?

Comment: @blubbiedevis he is creating a new workbook, the code does not add any more than 1. If by default there were 3 `wb.sheets[2];` would do. If there was one by default `wb.sheets.add();` and `ws2 = wb.sheets[2]` mean exactly same thing..

Comment: @mehow: It's never good practice to use hardcoded numbers in your code when it comes to Collections or Arrays. In this case, it might be alright, and might not cause the problem that he's experiencing, but he should nevertheless try to prevent such situations. If he is not getting the expected result, while he is using ws2 all the time,  then his ws2-initialisation is wrong and the error is likely to be found in the vicinity of the ws2-initialisation. That's my opinion...

Comment: @blubbiedevis there is so much I would change about this code but hey this is not a code review :)

Comment: This creates sheets but when adding data to the sheets it just replaces the data in a single sheet leaving aside the added sheets, not sure why